# Can I use my VSTO & VBA excel addins with Office365?

Tags: excel, vba, vsto, office365, office-interop

All the questions/answers I have seen so far are old and do not provide a definitive answer.

Also what can I use locally and what can I use online?

Comment: What version of Excel/Office do they work on?

Comment: Note that Office 365 is not a Web application. You get executables and etc. on your local computer. Some Office 365 packages include access to Office Online.

Comment: I am using local install of Excel 2016 which is part of Office 365 ProPlus.

Comment: @RichHolton

UDF:
Office.js allows creation of UDF?

PUBLISHING:
Currently we publish VBA/VSTO addins via msi/clickonce.
MS provides a way to use centralized deployment to publish Office Add-Ins which uses a xml manifest file.
https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/publish/centralized-deployment
Is there a way to publish VBA addins via this centralized deployment.
I know VSTO can't use it.

MULTI-THREADING:
We could not render into excel range from the UDF.
So we used VSTO to render into a excel range (not the calling cell), after a UDF is executed.
Can we do this via Office.js?

Comment: I don't know anything about Office.js, sorry.

Comment: @tejpratap As I mention in the answer, this is all about Office,js Add-ins technology. The reference for publishing you have mentioned as well. "Is there a way to publish VBA addins via this centralized deployment?" - No. Your current way to push it via msi is correct one.

Comment: @tejpratap SO is the QandA resource, not the forum. If you have another question like "So we used VSTO to render into a excel range (not the calling cell), after a UDF is executed. Can we do this via Office.js?" you should ask it separately. This will help others, who has the same question, quickly find the answer.

Comment: @SlavaIvanov thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> what can I use locally and what can I use online?

You may use your VSTO and VBA add-ins for Office Desktop application on Windows.

Office applications on Web (online) has extensibility via Office.js API. Microsoft current name is "Office Add-ins", you may try them by loading into your Office application (excel) from Office Store. If you want to develop add-in based on this technology I would suggest to start over here: [Office Add-ins platform overview](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins). The conception behind of this technology is "build once, use everywhere where Office runs". That means your add-in may work for Office Desktop on Windows, Office Desktop on Mac, Online versions as well as some mobile platforms (subject to [availability](https://dev.office.com/add-in-availability))

Comment: Haha yes, the current name is "Office Add-ins". To differentiate them from the other kind of Office add-ins called...Office Add-ins lol! They should have kept Apps for Office!

Comment: @EricLegault To be honest I liked "Apps for Office" better ;)

Comment: @EricLegault
Excel 2016 developer tab shows 3 Add-In buttons (1) Add-Ins (2) Excel Add-Ins (3) COM Add-Ins.
All documentation is out of whack now.
Bit and pieces everywhere and there are wide gaps for people to make assumptions.